# Land to a page of a module on connection to TYPO3 BE

Tags: connection, typo3, backend

Is it possible to select a landing page per user for the BE of TYPO3 for a module ?

I know it's possible to do it on the level of module with `overridePageModule`, the question is how to go further and precise even page ID, in the case, when we knows where the user should land.

For example, when a user of the group "Editors" connects to TYPO3 BE, will open module TemplaVoila, page 100.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution in a vanilla TYPO3.

Comment: What do You think, is it't difficult to implement ? With ExtJS Pagetree, probably ?

Comment: You need some JS that triggers the click (easy) and refreshes the different parts of the backend. Debug a click on the pagetree to see what you need to do.

Comment: I've managed to trigger the click : `TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree.select(10);`. Need to get it work on login only, if the user is in *Web* modules.

Comment: By the way, do You know how could I detect a handler of a click event handled by ExtJS ? I need to locate the source code, which is executed. Chrome shows event listeners, but points me always to ExtJS core library.

Comment: I have no idea about this.